# Some polytopes in $\mathbb R^n$ whose vertices have coordinates 1, -1 or 0

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers with $k\leq n$.

Let $P(n,k)$ be the convex hull in $\mathbb R^n$ of the $2^k {n \choose k}$ vectors whose exactly $k$ coordinates belong to $\{\pm 1\}$ all the others being equal to $0$.

Examples: $P(n,n)$ is the $n$-hypercube; $P(n,1)$ is the $n$-cross-polytope.

Viewed the two classical examples above, I expect that the $P(n,k)$'s have been studied already. Some references would be welcome.

I'm interested in the $f$-vector and more specifically to the facets (1-codimensional faces) of $P(n,k)$: how many and what kind of polytopes they are?

---

Added: thinking to this question, it comes to my mind that $2n$ of the facets of 
$P(n,k)$'s are $P(n-1,k-1)$ (assuming that $k>1$) and that all the other ones are $(n,k)$-hypersimplexes (assuming that $k<n$).

Answer (score 6):

View the two examples, I think $P(n,k)$ is the **$(n-k)$-[rectified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectification_(geometry)) $n$-hypercube** or the **$(k-1)$-rectified $n$-cross-polytope** (same thing).  I believe the notion of rectification will be very helpful for answering your other questions.

Properties of such polytpopes when $n$ and $k$ are small can be found on wikipedia.  For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectified_10-cubes

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know a good reference where the process of rectification of  a polytope is discussed?